# How to change container color on click when data is fetched from api in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to change container color on click when data is fetched from API in Flutter.
In this image, I am using listview builder to display 3 containers, which consist of some texts that are fetched from API, and what I want is that if I click on one of the containers, its color should change, and I only want one container's color to change at a time, meaning only one can be selected at a time.

[image: this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have an item to hold the value of the selected item and change the color according to the selected item value.

Below is en example:

```html
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int selectedItemID = 0;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> items = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDataFromAPI();
  }

  Future<void> getDataFromAPI() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    setState(() {
      items = [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Item 1",
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Item 2",
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "title": "Item 3",
        },
      ];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: items
              .map(
                (e) => Container(
                  height: 50,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  color: e["id"] == selectedItemID ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedItemID = e["id"];
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      e["title"],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: e["id"] == selectedItemID
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]